# threshold depth distance in image opencvsharp c# intel realsense

Tags: c#, opencv, realsense

This maybe a stupid question but how can you make a threshold so that the depth distance of the camera can get changed. Now I am using the Cv2.threshold to to that but with the otsu method the whole picture changes to one color instead of different kinds of a color.
The code used:

```
var colorizedDepth = colorizer.Process<VideoFrame>(depthFrame).DisposeWith(frames);
                            Mat testcd = new Mat(colorizedDepth.Height, colorizedDepth.Width, MatType.CV_8UC3, colorizedDepth.Data);
                            Mat testgd = new Mat();
                            Cv2.CvtColor(testcd, testgd, ColorConversionCodes.RGBA2GRAY);
                            Mat testbd = new Mat();
                            Cv2.Threshold(testgd, testbd, 0, 255, ThresholdTypes.Otsu | ThresholdTypes.Binary);
                            Cv2.ImShow("camera", testgd);
                            Cv2.WaitKey(0);
```

The code to get the colored depth is from the wrapper librealsense:
https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/wrappers/csharp
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong for the threshold so that the depth distances get changed?

Comment: Color is composed of three colors RGB (Red,Green,Blue) where each color is 8 bits. So if you have a picture that is 640 x 480 (depth)  you are trying to spread the color over 300,000 points.  So you can make all the points green if your range is not large enough.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question; do you want to set min/max limits on the depth values the camera returns? You can do that with the [threshold filter](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/wrappers/csharp/Intel.RealSense/Processing/ThresholdFilter.cs), which is used in a similar way to the colorizer filter.